# The method (Date) in the type is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Tags: java, mysql, date, jsp

Tengo un problema al realizar lo siguiente en jsp

```
En MySql
create database prueba;
use prueba;


create table insertar 
(
    nombre varchar(20) not null,
    apellidos varchar(20) not null,
    fechaViaje date
);

insert into insertar (nombre,apellidos,fechaViaje) values ("Juan","Lopez","2021-01-01");
```

Despues en Java esto:

```
package entities;

import java.sql.Date;

public class Libros {
    private String nombre;
    private String apellidos;
    private Date fechaViaje;
    
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public String getApellidos() {
        return apellidos;
    }
    public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }
    public Date getFechaViaje() {
        return fechaViaje;
    }
    public void setFechaViaje(Date fechaViaje) {
        this.fechaViaje = fechaViaje;
    }
    
    
    
}
```

En otro paquete

```
package model;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import db.MysqlDBConexion8;
import entities.Libros;

public class LibrosModel {
    
        public List<Libros> geListLibros(){
        
        List<Libros> listLibros = new ArrayList<Libros>();
        
        Connection cn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstm = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        
        
        try {
            
            cn = MysqlDBConexion8.getConexion();
            
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM insertar";
            pstm = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pstm.executeQuery();
            
            while (rs.next()) {
                Libros lib= new Libros();
                lib.setNombre(rs.getString("nombre"));
                lib.setApellidos(rs.getString("apellidos"));
                lib.setFechaViaje(rs.getDate("fechaViaje"));
                listLibros.add(lib);
                
            }
            
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        
        finally {
            try {
                
                if(rs!=null) rs.close();
                if(pstm!=null) pstm.close();
                if(cn!=null) cn.close();
                
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
        return listLibros;
        
    }
        public int createSubject(Libros sub) {
            int salida = 0;  
            Connection cn= null;
            PreparedStatement pstm= null;
            try {
                cn = MysqlDBConexion8.getConexion();
                
                String sql ="INSERT INTO insertar values(?, ?,?)";
                pstm=cn.prepareStatement(sql);
                pstm.setString(1, sub.getNombre());
                pstm.setString(2, sub.getApellidos());
                pstm.setDate(3, sub.getFechaViaje());
                
                salida = pstm.executeUpdate();
                
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                try {
                    
                    if(pstm!=null) pstm.close();
                    if(cn!=null) cn.close();
                    
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return salida;
        }
        
    }
```

Despues en servlet

```
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import entities.Libros;
import model.LibrosModel;


/**
 * Servlet implementation class SubjectServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/SubjectServlet")
public class SubjectServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public SubjectServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        String type = request.getParameter("type");
        
        if (type.equals("list")) {
            listLibros(request, response);
        } 
         else if (type.equals("register")) {
            register(request, response);
        } else if (type == "delete") {
            
        } else if (type == "edit") {
            
        } 
         
        
        
    }
    
    protected void listLibros(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException{
        
        LibrosModel model = new LibrosModel();
        
        List<Libros> data = model.geListLibros();
        request.setAttribute("data", data);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("insertar.jsp").forward(request, response);
        
    }
        protected void register (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
                throws ServletException, IOException{
            
            
        
            
            
            
            String nombre = request.getParameter("txtNombre");
            String apellidos = request.getParameter("txtApellido");
            String fechaViaje = request.getParameter("fechaViaje");
    
            
            Libros subject = new Libros();
            
            subject.setNombre(nombre);
            subject.setApellidos(apellidos);    
            //subject.setFechaViaje(Date.valueOf(fechaViaje).toString);
            subject.setFechaViaje(fechaViaje);  //Error

            'Aca es donde ocurre el problema que puse en el titulo'
           -->The method setFechaViaje(Date) in the type Libros is not applicable for the arguments (String)<--



            
            LibrosModel model = new LibrosModel();
            int resultado = model.createSubject(subject);
            
            if(resultado == 1) {
                listLibros(request, response);
            }else {
                request.setAttribute("msj", "Ocurrio un problema");
                request.getRequestDispatcher("insert.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }
            
            
        }
    
    

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

Alguien me podria ayudar con este problema.
Gracias
Alguien me podria ayudar con este problema.
Gracias
Alguien me podria ayudar con este problema.
Gracias
Alguien me podria ayudar con este problema.
Gracias
Alguien me podria ayudar con este problema.
Gracias
Alguien me podria ayudar con este problema.
Gracias
Alguien me podria ayudar con este problema.
Gracias
Alguien me podria ayudar con este problema.
Gracias

Comment: Saludos. Lo único que observo es que tu método de asignación **setFechaViaje** espera dato de tipo **Date** y le estas pasando un **String** debes sobrecargar ese método para realizar lo correspondiente con el **String** y convertirlo a **Date** para que lo reciba bien el **setFechaViaje(Date)** o realizar una conversión del dato a **Date** y pasar el convertirdo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema se encuentra en que no estas utilizando correctamente la función `subject.setFechaViaje(fechaViaje);` ya que le estas pasando un `String` en vez de un `Date` para hacer la conversión fácilmente te puedes crear una variable `Date fecha` y añadir el formato que este utilizando como aquí:

```
Date fecha = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(fechaViaje);
```

y acto seguido ya puedes llamar a tu función sin problema alguno de la siguiente manera:

```
subject.setFechaViaje(fecha);
```

Las librerías que tienes que importar son las siguientes:

`import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;` 
`import java.util.Date;`

Comment: Hola me aparece esto al poner lo que me envias                                                     The method setFechaViaje(java.sql.Date) in the type Libros is not applicable for the arguments (java.util.Date)

Comment: Añande este import, `import java.util.Date;` y borra este `import java.sql.Date;`

Comment: Si, borre el import de java.sql.Date en el servlet y me sigue apareciendo eso, debería borrar del package entities>Libros.java?

Comment: borrar el import de ese paquete no arreglaría nada, no se prueba a reescribir la línea pero con el import ya puesto, puede que tu IDE no este procesando el cambio de la variable

Comment: Si mi IDE no estaba procesando  el cambio, gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

El texto te dice claramente el error, la fecha la recibes como `String` pero el método necesita una fecha con el tipo de dato `Date`, lo que debes de hacer convertir fechaViaje a una variable de tipo Date(), para eso tienes que ver el formato de fecha que recibes.

```
String fechaViaje = "29/10/2021";

// Cambia el formato segun lo que tengas en la variable fechaViaje 
DateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = formato.parse(fechaViaje);

subject.setFechaViaje(date);
```

Comment: Hola al poner el codigo,me aparece este error
     Date date = formato.parse(fechaViaje);
      -->Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.util.Date to java.sql.Date<--

Comment: @Fabricio has importado el `Date` que no es. Borra el import de Date de tu objeto  e importa el `Date` de `java.util.Date`. Y lo mismo en todas partes que uses Date, en realidad.